# How to calculate scale value to fit a rotated element inside parent in CSS3

Tags: jquery, css

How can we calculate the scale value required to fit rotated element (img) inside its parent (div). Looking for a code that will work for any value of rotate.

```
<style>
img{
transform: rotate(20deg);
}
</style>

<div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>

<script>
//open to JS solution
</script>
```

[image: What is required]

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this, because it's going to be rather complicated.

Comment: I was sure it would be complicated, posted this with a hope that someone might know a ready made plugin or css3 property that i don't know

Comment: I worked out a *partial* answer and in typing it up I found an error. Bleh. `sin(Θ)*s/h/w` will work if you've got a TALL image, otherwise `cos(Θ)*s/w/h` for a WIDE image.  *I think.* Can someone generalize?

Comment: @Draco18s check the maths on the duplicate :)

Comment: @DaniP That looks like at least what I was *thinking.* I may have attempted a shortcut that wasn't valid though. But yeah, current corner-to-corner vs. maximal corner-to-corner as a ratio. I was thinkin' I might be able to cheat using values from sine/cosine.